# Time Cisco Router reload not always mentioned

Tags: router, cisco, cisco-ios

Im trying to measure our cisco router availability data based on downtime happened. I assume from show version, the time mentioned in tag "System returned to ROM" is when reload started, and next line "System restarted at" is when router back online again. The only thing confusing is RouterA node showing time when returned to ROM while RouterB is not.

Does anyone know the different? And how to make RouterB shows the exact time router reloaded next time on the show version command?

Thanks
Hadit

RouterA#show version
Cisco IOS Software, s72033_rp Software (s72033_rp-ITPK9V-M), Version 12.2(33)IRI, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2012 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Fri 04-May-12 14:04 by prod_rel_team
ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.2(17r)S4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
 RouterA uptime is 4 years, 11 weeks, 5 days, 17 hours, 27 minutes
Uptime for this control processor is 4 years, 11 weeks, 5 days, 17 hours, 19 minutes
**System returned to ROM by reload at 00:01:24 JAVT Thu Oct 11 2012 (SP by reload)**
*System restarted at 00:05:58 JAVT Thu Oct 11 2012*
System image file is "bootdisk:s72033-itpk9v-mz.122-33.IRI.bin"
Last reload type: Normal Reload

RouterB#show version 
Cisco IOS Software, s72033_rp Software (s72033_rp-ITPK9V-M), Version 12.2(33)IRI, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2012 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Fri 04-May-12 14:04 by prod_rel_team
ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.2(17r)S4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
 RouterB uptime is 4 years, 12 weeks, 6 days, 17 hours, 51 minutes
Uptime for this control processor is 4 years, 12 weeks, 6 days, 17 hours, 54 minutes
**System returned to ROM by reload (SP by reload)**
*System restarted at 00:16:21 JAVT Wed Oct 3 2012*
System image file is "bootdisk:s72033-itpk9v-mz.122-33.IRI.bin"
Last reload type: Normal Reload

Comment: SInce this doesn't really appear to be related to computer programming, but rather the programming of cisco routers, there are other Stack Exchange sites this would more likely be a better fit for.  You might start with http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cisco

Answer (score -1):

Do not rely on those commands to measure availability, you are much better off using a proper uptime tool to handle this for you, there are several free ones like Zabbix, PRTG and others and commercial ones like Solarwinds, HP NNM and others.

The output of those commands may change without notice hence not a good idea to rely on them for things that c an be automated using proper tools.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Unfortunately my client who owns the routers doesnt want to put any external tools for security reason.. I was assuming if reload done by system will not show the specific time on line "System returned to ROM..." while if reload initiated by command will have the specific time on that line, can it be like that?

Comment: The problem is that the answer is yes and no depending on hw and OS versions

Comment: @hadit for security reasons? That's weird cause most people use tools to monitor to increase their security not the other way around